# pointer in function on C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm revisiting linked list data structure, and my textbook created a function like this :

```
void *insert_beginning(){
    struct node *new_node;
    new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    printf("\n Enter the data : ");
    scanf("%d", &new_node->data);

    new_node->next = link;
    link = new_node;
}
```

What does `void *insert_beginning` mean? 
This method also giving me a warning `No return, in function returning non-void`

And why does it will error if I delete the `*`?

NB : My linked list project run flawlessly with those functions, but I'm just curious. It has nothing to do with linked list

Comment: Your function returns `void *`, that is a pointer to type `void` but there is no `return` statement somewhere before the final `}` - hence the warning. If you don't want to return anything replace `void *` with `void`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration `void *insert_beginning` means that the name of the function is `insert_beginning` and that the return type should be a `void` pointer, which is, in a certain sense, an untyped pointer. However, the implementation of the funtion has no `return` statement, which causes the warning.

It is difficult to tell without more context, but either the return type should be `void` instead of `void *` or there should be some return statement like `return new_node` which passes a pointer to the newly allocated memory to the caller.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, its working fine with just void return type. I just need to clean my project LoL. To be honest, I dont really understand about untyped pointer. But this will do for now, Im prioritizing data structures over c language